# C++ how to draw line chart using WTL?

Tags: c++, charts, wtl

I am new to C++ and WTL, does WTL provide good API's to display line (stacked area, column) charts?
      Or do we need to use 3rd party library to integrate the same with our existing C++ code?
    It would be great if i can some pointers to examples .....i am looking for very basic line 2D chart.
   The application is written in C++ and use WTL for some of the GUI components .....and platform is windows

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WTL provides you with some classes that wrap GDI API and handles, so you can obviously paint variety of charts, you are just going to do it right from scratch. That is, dissecting your client area into chart area, legend, axis and son on. If you were looking for a solution ot use of of the box, WTL does not have anything close. You can certainly integrate third party libraries, ActiveX controls, or even [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/) hosted by IE ActiveX control on your window, where you pass data synthesizing JS script on runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ...I have an application written in C++ and installed on windows .....so can i still use google API's ? (i have add this info in my question)

Comment: Using Google API is one of the options which makes sense, and it is up to you whether it is acceptable for you or not. Google Chart Tools are well documented, free and quite powerful. If your application would instantiate an IE control and load HTML page there synthesized on runtime with your data and a reference to online Google chart API, then it would be able to present the charts, easily and nicely, however loading the APIs online on runtime. As I mentioned, it is one of the options. Traditional third party ActiveX control might work out better for you.

Comment: Thank you, I have used Google DOJO API's for developing a portal in the past...and thought of the approach but was wondering if we had any option within WTL...so that the reports display is within the application.